# php - htaccess issue on linux

Tags: php, mod-rewrite

I created a custom php MVC on windows and it worked great without any bugs but on linux I am facing some bugs like I am unable to access any other controller than my default one.

e.g: `localhost/mymvc`  - This url redirects me to my default controller

but when I try to open any other controller e.g: `localhost/mymvc/projects`  I get a "404 not found error"

Here are my functions that redirects:

```
/* ***** Getting URL ***** */
$url = isset($_GET['url']) ? $_GET['url'] : null;
$url = explode('/',$url);

/* ***** When URL does not contain any controller name call default controller ***** */
if(empty($url[0])){
    $defaultpage = HOME;
    require 'application/controllers/'.$defaultpage.'.php';
    $controller = new $defaultpage();
    $controller->loadModel($defaultpage);
    $controller->index();
    return false;
}

/* ***** When URL contains controller name ***** */
$page = 'application/controllers/'.$url['0'].'.php';
if(file_exists($page)){
    require $page;
}else{
    $this->error();
}
$controller = new $url[0];
$controller->loadModel($url[0]);
```

I am sure there are no bugs in here but still wanted you guys to review. I think have issues with .htaccess file so here is what I have in it:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Are you sure mod_rewrite is turned on? You can turn it on by typing `a2enmod rewrite` in your console. Then simply restart Apache. I wonder if it will work, but it's a good start.

Comment: Also check 'allowoverride all' is set as well in the htconf, and you may need 'options +followsymlinks' in the htaccess.

Comment: @Jelmer, be aware that `a2enmod` is a Debian/Ubuntu thing, not an official Apache tool.

Comment: @Charles Oh okay. Did not know that, thanks. I have just set up my own server (Debian) today so I am kinda new to it :)

Comment: also, be aware that windows is case-insensitive, whereas Linux is case-sensitive, so, if your page is called home.php, requiring HOME.php will work under windows but not under Linux.

Answer (score 0):

**Undestanding your htaccess**

Rewrite engine will be enabled:
`RewriteEngine On`

Base directory for rewrite will be /:
`RewriteBase /`

If request match a not existing file, continue:
`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f`

If request match a not existing directory, continue:
`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d`

If request match a not existing symbolic link, continue:
`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l`

Rewrite to index.php:
// L means if the rule matches, don't process any more RewriteRules below this one.
// QSA Appends any query string from the original request URL to any query string created in the rewrite target
`RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]`

As we can see there is no actual problem with your htaccess.
Now you need to check if you have mod_rewrite enable in your apache.

You can just output phpinfo() and check if it's enabled.

Now into your PHP.

First be sure to remember that linux is case sensitive.

Debug:

After this line

`$page = 'application/controllers/'.$url['0'].'.php';`

Add this var_dump

`var_dump($page);`

Check if the path is correct and then do the rest of your debug analysis!

Regards